# How to replace ^M with blank space C++

Tags: c++, string, boost, std

I am writing code in C++ where I have an input string which goes like

> \n{^M    "id": "two",^M    "guid":
>   "49709bb3-7444-40bf-9032-cc65e36d26f5",^M    "isActive": true,^M
>   "balance": "1645.00",^M    "picture": "http://placehold.it/32x32",^M
>   "age": 28,^M    "name": "Elvira Odom",^M    "gender": "female",^M
>   "company": "Homelux",

I have no control over the input string.

I need to print this string which is stored in p1f0->str to a file and parse it for other purposes.

But the ^M character messes up things while parsing, and hence, I would like to get rid of it.

So, in order to get rid of the ^M characters, I'm doing this and it is not working-

```
struct specialStr {
  uint32 len;
  char str[0];
}
specialStr p111;
p111....
....
std::string raww = (char*) p111->str;
boost::replace_all( raww, "^M", " ");
strncpy(p111->str, raww.c_str(), sizeof(raww));
p111->len = (uint32) (raww.size());
p111->str[p111->len - 1] = 0;
```

But there seems to be no effect at all.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean? What I pasted was not compileable code. It was just a sample snippet!

Comment: `p111->str` has size `0`...

Comment: What is this: `std::string raww = (char*) p111->str;`???

Comment: I did that so I can use boost/std string functions on the char array

Comment: Are you sure the `^M` isn't `\r`?

Comment: I understand ^M is ASCII code 13. I just want to get rid of it. would std::replace help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence `^M` is how your editor displays control-code M, ASCII code 13: CARRIAGE RETURN.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII

You can easily encode it as `"\r"` in C or C++.

Comment: Great. This is the direction I was expecting the discussion to head. Thanks for your comment.

I understand that ^M is windows carriage return 0x0D 0x0A. But, how do i replace that with spaces, so i just get rid of all ^M. Is that possible?

Comment: CR is 0x0D (0x0A is the linefeed, in Windows text files CR+LF denote a newline, but that's probably unrelated. It might explain how you ended up with the stray CR aka ^M chars)

Comment: Gotcha.
>>You can easily encode it as "\r" in C or C++.

How do I do that? I have no way to change my input, but I can edit/replace characters on that string I receive (with ^M). How do I encode that as \r?

Something like this?
std::replace( raww.begin(), raww.end(), '^M', ' ');

But this doesn't work. :(

Comment: Just type in the characters '\r'. Like you typed in the characters '^M', except they're different keys on your keyboard.

Comment: I changed it to -

`std::replace( raww.begin(), raww.end(), '\r', ' ');`

But that doesn't seem to have any effect either. The file I eventually write into has those ^M as is.

Comment: Bump bump! Someone help please?

Comment: A lot of my data and code is confidential and I cannot share it. Anyway, I found the issue myself, and I fixed it! Thanks

Comment: We all know how that works. That's why we reduce and reduce until we have the cause. Glad you found it.